# Events in Canvas works only for last element

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I use `ListView` to display list of `Button`s. While using `StackPanel` or `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel` of the `ListView`, everything works fine. When I try `Canvas` only the last one button from a collection is working, others doesn't even change their background when mouse is over them. Can I make all them work normally?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="{Binding margin}" Width="40" Height="40" Click=button_click />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

code behind:

```
public class object1
{
    public double x0 { get; set; }
    public double y0 { get; set; }
    public Thickness margin { get { return new Thickness(x0, y0, 0, 0); } }

    public object1(double x, double y)
    {
        x0= x;
        y0 = y;
    }
}

public MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<object1> collection1 {get;set;}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;     

        collection1=new ObservableCollection<object1>();
        collection1.Add(new object1(20,20));
        collection1.Add(new object1(20,80));
        collection1.Add(new object1(80,20));
        collection1.Add(new object1(80,80)); // ONLY THAT ONE WORKS
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: What is possibly unclear here? There is a collection of buttons and only one is working.

Comment: You won't get any help here with an attitude like that. When users politely ask you for more information, it is generally a good idea to provide it... but only if you want your question answered.

Comment: True, but there is no more information about this issue.

Comment: Wow, really? You said *While using StackPanel or WrapPanel everything works fine*, but you didn't show or even tell us how you used them. You said *When I try Canvas*, but you didn't show us how you 'tried' `Canvas`. You said *others doesn't even change their background when mouse is over them*, but I don't see any `MouseOver` handlers. There is *always* more information about every issue. By asking questions here, you have a responsibility to help us to help you, but as you are not helping us, I won't bother either.

Comment: There is a code attached, where you can see, that Canvas is used as ItemsPanel in ListView. Using WrapPanel means setting ItemsPanel as ItemsPanel. About second one: default behaviour of buttons in wpf is to change color when mouse is over them, you don't need your own mouseover handler.

Comment: @Sheridan, it was there since the beginning, you just didn't paid enough attention nor gave it a thought... Bashing on newbies isn't really a way to go, especially when they've provided the info.

Comment: Rico, the only single thing that changed is that you've swapped `<Canvas />` for `<StackPanel />`? The parent element shouldn't affect the events, unless there's some error in data binding or something else...

Comment: I'm not 'bashing' anyone... I was just asking for some more information so that I could fully understand the problem before helping.

Comment: @walther yes indeed! The only thing I did was change `<Canvas />` into `<StackPanel />` and everything worked fine! Coming back to `<Canvas />` and the issue returns.

Comment: It sounds like all four `Button`s actually *are* there, but just on top of each other because you haven't set any positions in the `Canvas` for them.

Comment: I didn't attached the code, that set buttons position not to create mess, but it is there and buttons are displayed correctly.

Comment: The problem seems to be tied to the ListView and not to Canvas itself. If you hardcode the elements, it will work as expected. The problem appears only when using the ListView, maybe it has something to do with the positioning or registering active areas (ListView is kinda forcing people to select elements). Can't provide a solution yet though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way in which you do the positioning of the Buttons with a `Margin` inside the `ListViewItem`. All the ListViewItems lie on top of each other in the Canvas, and only the topmost gets input events.

Move the Margin binding out of the `ItemTemplate` into an `ItemContainerStyle`, so that it sets the `Margin` of a `ListViewItem` instead of a `Button`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding margin}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="40" Height="40" .../>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

When using a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel` I'd strongly suggest to use the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties for positioning item containers. You would usually bind them to properties of the data item type, like your `x0` and `y0`:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding x0}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding y0}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I suggested that, but the question author replied that *I didn't attached the code, that set buttons position not to create mess, but it is there and buttons are displayed correctly.* It *seems* as if the problem relates to only one of the four `Buttons` having the normal default mouse over states.

Comment: Thanks, but displaying is not the issue here. It's the fact, that all buttons except the one don't work.

Comment: @RicoW I guess it would make sense to show your code that sets button positions. Maybe it is the cause of your problem, although you're sure it isn't.

Comment: @Clemens OK, I did it.

Comment: NO WAY, changing the way how I bind position of object solved the problem! Strange thing, when i tried <Button Canvas.Left="{Binding x0}" ... /> it didn't worked. I don't understand it, but finally I can move on with my project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Button does not become a direct child of the Canvas. There is a ListViewItem for each item in the ListView, and each ListViewItem has a Button as its Content. That's all explained in the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.